# Power Plane arrangement on multi-voltage PCB

Tags: power, pcb, ground, pcb-layers, routing

I am designing a PCB with 4 different voltages other than GND: PV+, 5V0, 12V0, VSYS

I am trying to get out with a 4-layers PCB design. I have no particular high-frequency signals on the board (a couple of I2C and UART lines). Since the board is quite large, I planned to avoid using fat, long power traces to deliver power to the components and instead go with power planes.

Every component is located on the bottom layer of the board. This is my current Stackup:

L1: 12V plane on the bottom half the board, a couple of tracks and vias on the upper half of the board, no components. This is just to deliver 12V to another board.

L2: VSYS plane (VSYS is around 14.4 V)

L3: GND plane

L4: Here I have most connection between components and a couple of buck converters (taking VSYS as input and outputting 12V and 5V, located far apart from the ICs).

Problem is that I have to route 5V0 from one side of the board to the other (for design reason). Could I just copper pour L4 with a 5V0 plane and provide enough clearance between the plane and the components that work on different voltages? The resulting Stackup would be:

L1: 12V0

L2: VSYS (14V4)

L3: GND

L4: 5V0

As an alternative, could I split L2 between 5V0 and VSYS? Note that some tracks on L1 would cross the planes across their split line.

Comment: There's very rarely any benefit to dedicating one plane,let alone two, to power distribution. Far better to have a ground plane, and three routing layers. Top tip, make two adjacent layers Manhattan (one layer North-South tracks, the other layer East-West tracks), that allows systematic routing of any point to point track without having to cut others. As they are adjacent, you could use blind vias between those two layers to improve space on the other layers.

Comment: do you know the difference in nH from a long fat trace and a layer and how that affects ripple from source regulation and CMOS transition current?

Comment: @Neil_UK Is it just a matter of "no benefit" or it can actually be harmful to have one or multiple power planes?

Comment: @GianfrancoDiDomenico If you have multiple power planes, you are (A) forcing all your signal tracks onto a single plane which makes routing difficult, may compromise best routing, you'll deviate onto other planes for cross-overs sacrificing their integrity and (B) you may be tempted to be lazy and think 'planes, it's all solved', and not think about where current is actually flowing. In a good board layout, you know where the currents are flowing, to avoid crosstalk between areas that should not talk to each other. Planes often, but not always, do much of this for you.